# xpath sum of all preceding-siblings matching a value of tag in node

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm stuck on the following problem:

Using an xpath expression I have to sum all preceding siblings matching a tag's value.
Actually I'm on the last node element with a certain id.

Relative to this position I have to output the sum of all preceding siblings matching the the same id located in ./id

I am limited to xpath 2.0 for architectural reasons and have to find a solution by using a xpath expression.

sample structure

```
<root>
...
<element>
    <id>198</id>
    <sum>1</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>198</id>
    <sum>0</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>267</id>
    <sum>2</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>267</id>
    <sum>0</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>267</id>
    <sum>0</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>267</id>
    <sum>0</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>3123</id>
    <sum>34</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>3123</id>
    <sum>0</sum>
</element>
<element>
    <id>3123</id>
    <sum>0</sum>
</element>
...
</root>
```

i tried:

`sum(preceding-sibling::element[./id = self::*/id]/sum)`

the result of the expression did not match the expected value: 
The expression summs up the values of all  Tags that are located before the starting element and not only the specific ones.

I'd like to get the following results:

last element with id 198  the result should be 1

last element with id 267  the result should be 2

last element with id 3123 the result should be 34

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 2.0 you need to use set up a variable and use a variable resolver (how you do that depends on the XPath API) and do e.g. `sum(preceding-sibling::element[id = $el/id]/sum)`. With XPath 3.0 you could do `let $el := . return sum($el/preceding-sibling::element[id = $el/id]/sum)`.